# How to add title below node in mermaid diagram

Tags: mermaid

I want to remove title from mermaid node and add image and title below node. Same as below image.

How to add title below node in mermaid diagram?

[image: Sample Image To View]

I want to remove title from mermaid node and add image and title below node

Comment: Can you share the Mermaid source that you are using? And provide a rendered Mermaid chart instead of a hand-drawn chart?